# Fit Images on php

Tags: php, jquery, image

I want to create a gallery and i'm doing it with PHP.
What I want to know is if there is any way to fit images in a certain space.
Imagine that I have a div with 500px by 350px, and I have 15 images with different sizes. I want to fit them in way to put them next to each other independent the size of each.
Here some examples of what I want:

http://tympanus.net/Development/GammaGallery/
This example is created with jQuery, but I want in PHP. Unless it's really easier with jQuery.

Attention: I don't want you guys make me the code, I just want some ideas to clear my doubt and a little push in order to continue my work.

Comment: PHP won't do this for you, you might want to learn about CSS ;)

Comment: Yes PHP won't work because its a server-side script i.e. in the slideshow every time the user will try to scroll to the next image, he will have to reload the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cant do this for you ..You may need to use css for doing this..But you can add an image into background,styling donts on the picture with php gd library..

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: And it is possible connect jquery and php and work together to do that?

Comment: you can use php to fetch images from your file system maybe and then display it on the webpage.. then you can use jquery and css to style the display any way you want it